# Elabore una función tipo void que reciba una palabra e imprima la letra que se repita más veces en la función main()

Tags: c

cómo dice el título. El problema es el siguiente: **Elabore una función tipo void que reciba una palabra e imprima la letra que se repita más veces en la
función main().**
Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo para que sólo imprima la letra que se repita más veces en vez de todas las letras? Hasta ahora este es mi progreso:

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? No sabemos dónde te quedaste atascado.

Comment: La idea es que solamente imprima la letra que se repite la mayor cantidad de veces en vez de todas.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible forma de hacer lo que quieres es ayudándote de un arreglo que guarde la cantidad que se repite cada letra:

```
char letras[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
int repeticiones[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Si la cadena fuese por ejemplo "aa bbbb e iii o uuuuu", el arreglo `repeticiones` se debería verse así:

| Posición | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Repeticiones | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| Letras | a | e | i | o | u |

Dicho esto, puedes crear una función que se encargue de contar una sola letra como esta:

```
int contarLetra(char* cadena, char letra)
{
    int longitud = strlen(cadena);
    int contador = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        if (tolower(cadena[i]) == letra)
            contador++;
    }

    return contador;
}
```

Solo te falta ver cuál letra es la que más se repite. Puedes hacerlo fácilmente recorriendo el arreglo con un código como el siguiente.

```
int maximo = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nLetras; i++){
    if (cantidades[i] > maximo)
        maximo = cantidades[i];
}

// Puede haber varias letras que se repitan la misma cantidad de veces.
// Por eso se recorre 2 veces el arreglo.
printf("\nLa letras que más se repiten son:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < nLetras; i++){
    if (cantidades[i] == maximo)
        printf("%c\n", letras[i]);
}
```

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##pVNLbtswEN3rFIMEhaXaaexFN3EcwO0qQG6QeMFSI4WAPHRJCv0EPkzP0CPkXlVnKEq1inQRdBYUNHx8894MqS90o6juunNDumlLhGsfSmPfPd5kpylnqJ7mdPh2QEll5yVWhhDoDoNTHt5nmaEA2lJQLuZy/ajcW9CqRFILkD9oZKNY99i9MpQX2VMGHHHb36@Wy906Jg5cPVT52S3VDj1CSypxXcFZ0WOqGoPP/QL42ALEAwn5yBfL@fukcQcbeIKZmi1ghrIYWaws7QyO6eDlJXxskV14Kad6jrgT/SkKpmQZf7Eu5XyUZB3kgjScX675cz30iH/m86K3GyX@4TLCcto79pTEm10yexz1fWi9ZnmNgoP1RpvnnwQ8nSaJFSLYP//w4PCAgQGW0AOSIPoWjn726qvZ2yj1tfJNBfnUwk2iK0aMxFhiAp54Gmb9QHfJg4fPLfYmePbswwTW7y1dPdA4/f/Rutm8KHZQ8kZznZdmICvfOrleeUo6DK0j6eDxFY8g3XvBN5ZqE9qSbfCja5DyHp/4R8qSDcdJ/dP@wNT7j7BpE4Jt7Bd0qYAYk04kRaeNGArO55NJJa/DLlvuuu12C590Cd85AOFWAlqJ7JeuGlX77oLf5kavVr8B).

Por cierto, [se desaconseja el uso de `gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets#Notes). Puedes reemplazarlo por `fgets` o `gets_s`.